# MSSQL query to compare uniqueness

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, grouping

I have been knocking my head for quite some time now for a solution to this. Would be great if someone could help me with this:-

I have three columns `Recipe, alt recipe` and `Component`. Structure is as below:-

```
Recipe  Alt_Recipe  Recipe_component 
1430    1   110000000
1430    1   170000051
1430    2   110000000
1430    2   170000051
1430    3   110000000
1430    3   170000051
```

I need to find cases where components (All of them exclusively) get repeated  in any Alternative recipe. For eg:- Recipe 1430 has 2 components in Alt recipe 1 namely ***110000000*** and ***170000051***. If these two are found anywhere in any OTHER alt recipe (Like 2 or 3 in this case) I need to point them out. Also, if alt recipe 3 has these two components ALONGWITH some other component its fine and should not be pointed out.

Thanks a lot for any help that comes across my way! :)

Comment: As Mentioned in the subject line, the tool i am using is MSSQL and i need to write an sql statement to achieve the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acheived by doing similar to what oracle does with LISTAGG.

1. Group components by alt recipe by using XML PATH (create a dataset)
2. Create a dataset of ideal counts by doing a recipe, count(distinct Alt)
3. Join above datasets  based on recipe and count1 <> count2.
4. Resulting dataset is list of exceptions.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self join and aggregation:

```
select rc1.Recipe, rc1.Alt_Recipe, rc2.Alt_Recipe as hasSameComponents
from recipecomponents rc1 left join
     recipecomponents rc2
     on rc1.recipe = rc2.recipe and rc1.Component = rc2.Component and
        rc1.Alt_Recipe <> rc2.Alt_Recipe
group by rc1.Recipe, rc1.Alt_Recipe, rc2.Alt_Recipe
having count(*) = count(rc2.recipe);
```

The logic is to match the components for every pair of "alt" recipes.  Then simply count the number that match the first ones.

Comment: This query is not working due to no aggregation but usage of group by.. Any aggregates on the select statement you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```sql
select recipe, count(*)
from dbo.receipts
group by recipe, alt_recipe, recipe_component
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Nope. I tried this, it wont work as we are grouping by all three columns.

Comment: Ok then I misunderstood your question. Still unclear what you want to achieve. Can you give some examples? (Maybe formatted for better readability would be nice)